# Format a date time string from YYYY/MM/DD to MM/DD/YYYY with no time

Tags: c#, date, parsing

I need to take a time that is a string saved like this: "2016-12-26" and convert it to "12/26/2016" so from yyyy-mm-dd to mm/dd/yyyy I am doing so below however I am getting the time too and I need just the date.

Code I'm using:

```
  var parseBooking = DateTime.ParseExact(bookingStartDate.Replace("-", string.Empty), "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Use the `Date` property of a `DateTime` object

Comment: What do you mean "stored"? Is it in a field in a database (if so, what is the type of that field), or in a text file of some sort?

Comment: @Gilad I'm not sure I understand.  I'm not seeing a date property.

Comment: @NicolePhillips parseBooking.Date

Comment: Note that you could also just do `var parseBooking = DateTime.ParseExact(bookingStartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @NicolePhillips - `parseBooking.Date`

Comment: @DStan It is a field quried from standard salesforce that is saved as a string like this: "2016-12-26"

Comment: @Gilad it is still returning the time

Comment: DateTime.Parse("2016-12-26").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); should return you what you want. you don't event need the ParseExact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conver bookingStartDate to a DateTime object, then use String.Format on the datetime:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(bookingStartDate , "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var parseBooking = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt)
```

If not create a DateTime object from your string and then do the above.

Comment: so would that mean I would need to parse out the year, month date to match the format of the object? as the new object wants to take in int values and these are strings.

Comment: You could do 
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(bookingStartDate);

to create a date. If you need to, you can pass in an IFormatProvider if the Date format isn't standard for you.

Answer (score 0):

> "2016-12-26" ... to "12/26/2016"

Probably the fastest algorithm in the world:

```
var a = "2016-12-26";
var b = new string(new[] { a[5], a[6], '/', a[8], a[9], '/', a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3] });
```